# combine 3 arrays with default keys

Tags: php

I have this function, keys are defined by an array `$idForKeys`:

```
$idForKeys  = array('k1','k2');
$idForValues  = array('k1','k2');
$login  = array('logA','logB');
$password  = array('passA','passB');
$result = array();

foreach ($idForKeys as $id => $key) {
        $result[$key] = array(
          'id'    => $idForValues[$id],
          'login' => $login[$id],
          'password' => $password[$id],
        );
    }
```

Output `$result` : `Array ( [k1] => Array ( [id] => k1 [login] => logA [password] => passA ) [k2] => Array ( [id] => k2 [login] => logB [password] => passB ) )`

How to combine this arrays with default keys:`[0][1]` instead `[k1][k2]` ?

Comment: Can you post sample array data and your expected output?

Comment: A bit unclear but array_combine?

Comment: already posted.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just like that?

```
$result = [];
foreach ($idForKeys as $id => $key) {
    $result[] = array(
      'id'    => $idForValues[$id],
      'login' => $login[$id],
      'password' => $password[$id],
    );
}
```